# Enable editing option only if the user is authenticated, else display the information normally

Tags: angularjs

So I'm still new to Angularjs, but I'm wondering if it's possible to show certain things if the user isn't authenticated while full access if a user authenticates without duplicating the template? A solution that I could think of is using ng-show and ng-hide where certain features will show up if `isAuthenticated` is true. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Check out this project `https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth`. It should show you all kinds of neat tricks.

Comment: This is great, but I'm not using Nodejs for the backend and it seems from the commenters that they have successfully implemented this using other backend languages. But thanks still!

Comment: Here is another approach: `http://vyazici.blogspot.com/2012/09/angularjs-authentication-service.html`

Answer (score 0):

I would use ng-if because this completely removes the DOM as opposed to just hiding it.

You can use the resolve function in routing to determine whether a user is authenticated and authorized before the page loads so they won't see the edit option flash and disappear.

Remember that since this is javascript the user can always modify the code to allow editing to show up.  Make sure on the server side that editing is blocked if the user is not authorized to do so.